# Static IPv4 in QEMU

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm fairly new to QEMU and am attempting to provide static IP addresses to the network interfaces while bringing up the QEMU images via command line.
The command is like below:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -smp 2 -hda disk.img -net nic,model=i82557b,vlan=1,macaddr=00:06:04:00:0a:01 -net user,vlan=1,net=10.10.10.1/24
```

As per this, I'm assigning one network interface whose IP address should be `10.10.10.1`

When the OS comes up, the mac address gets assigned properly. However, the IP address always defaults to `10.10.10.15`

As per the [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-x86_64.1.en.html), the X.X.X.15 is probably because of DHCP - which I do not wish to configure.

How do I provide a specfic IP address to bind to the network interface?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using libvirt?